# Integrate barcode scanner in Java web application

Tags: jakarta-ee

We have a Java web application, in which we need to scan the barcode from the book and retrieve ISBN number of the book. Is there any open source plugin or library which I can use to integrate into my application and thereby scan the barcode. Any idea would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

When you correctly install a barcode scanner and scan a code, it will usually act as a keyboard (keyboard wedge). Thus all you need is have an input field that will capture the code. The scanner will send an "enter" at the end thus the form can be auto-submitted.

Comment: I want to integrate the barcode scanner functionality within my application, I will not install any external barcode reader

Comment: Could you please better describe your intended architecture, use-cases, and platforms on which you want to make the application available for end-users?